# Cant figure out why this code is crashing

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am running this code in GRACE which is the implementation of [Common Music](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/),  which is implemented in [S7 Scheme](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/s7.html) and uses [SAL](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm/res/doc/cm.html#sal) as the language.

I have the following definitions:

```
(define (shuffle-no-reps lst prev)  
    (loop for l = (shuffle lst)
          until (not (= prev (list-ref l 0)))
          finally (return l)))

(define (sampling3 reps notes)
  (let* ((len (length notes)))
    (loop for i below reps
             for j = (mod i len)
             for k = (list-ref notes j)
             do
             (if (= j (- len 1)) (set! notes (shuffle-no-reps notes k)))
             (print k))))

(define (sampling4 reps notes)
  (let* ((len (length notes)))
    (loop for i below reps
             for j = (mod i len)
             do
             (if (= j 0) (set! notes (shuffle notes)))
             (print (list-ref notes j)))))
```

Both `sampling3` and `sampling4` randomly shuffle a list a few times but `sampling3` uses `shuffle-no-reps` instead of `shuffle`.

`shuffle-no-reps` is supposed to make sure that the newly shuffled list does not start with the same value as the previously generated value.

I can run `shuffle-no-reps` like this no problem

```
(shuffle-no-reps '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)
```

and it performs as expected.

I can also run `sampling4`

```
(sampling4 10 '(60 62 63 65 67 69 70 72))
```

and it performs as expected but when I try

```
(sampling3 10 '(60 62 63 65 67 69 70 72))
```

the whole application crashes as soon as the `shuffle-no-reps` function is called.

This is driving me insane as I spent already 3 days trying to figure out why this code is crashing.

Any help would be appreciated!